# Looking for lots of real texts written by humans with user-metadata

Tags: nlp, social-media, text

I am an NLP researcher and for the purpose of my ongoing work I need lots of textual data produced by real human beings. It's probably not so hard to obtain, but it's important that it's also contains user meta-information like gender, age, country, education, native language and so on. Topic preference is common talk.

I would be grateful for a link to such datasets or any ideas of how to harvest such a data.